# How to get multiple selected items in asp.net listbox and show in a textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net

i am trying to add the selected items from the listbox to the textbox with the comma seperated between each other. but it is only reading the first element of the selected items every time.if i select three values holding ctrl its only passing the fist elemnt of selected items

```
if (ListBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {

            //   int count = ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count;
            if (TextBox1.Text == "")
                TextBox1.Text += ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            else
                TextBox1.Text += "," + ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
```

if listbox contain :1,2,3,4
example output inside textbox: 1,1,1,1
expected output: 1,2,3,4  (for evry selection it shouldnt display the already selected value again)

Answer (score 3):

```
var selectedItemText =   new List<string>();
    foreach (var li in ListBox1.Items)
    {
       if (li.Selected == true)
        {
         selectedItemText.Add(li.Text);
        }
    }
```

**Then**

```
var result =   string.Join(selectedItemText,",");
```

Comment: You can directly use `ListBox1.SelectedItems` instead of having to check in each one if it is selected.

Comment: It is asp.net control it does not have SelectedItems property. I thinks winform has

Comment: Didn't see the ASP.NET tag, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

The `ListBox` has a `SelectedItems` property, that you can iterate over:

```
foreach (var item in ListBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    TextBox1.Text += "," + item.ToString();
}
```

At the end you need to remove the first "," as it will be in front of the first items string representation:

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(1, TextBox1.Text.Legth - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var selected =  string.Join(",", yourListBox.Items.GetSelectedItems());

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ListItem> GetSelectedItems(
           this ListItemCollection items)
    {
        return items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected);
    }
}
```