# How to select multiple values in a Listbox from VB when I have certain values flowing from the database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code in vb, where I am trying to select multiple items in the aspx page from vb. But it ends up selecting only 1 item every time. What to do and how do I resolve this?

ASPX Code:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ddlmsapplications" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

VB Code:

```
ms_applications = ds.Item("microsoft_applications")

                        Dim ms_array() As String = ms_applications.Split(",")
                        Dim ms_list As List(Of String) = ms_array.ToList()

                        For Each item As String In ms_list
                            ddlmsapplications.SelectedValue = item
                        Next
```

Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above functionality can be achieved through the following code:

```
ms_applications = ds.Item("microsoft_applications")
    Dim ms_array() As String = ms_applications.Split(",")
                            Dim ms_list As List(Of String) = ms_array.ToList()

                            For Each item As ListItem In ddlmsapplications.Items
                                For Each element As String In ms_list
                                    If item.Value = element Then
                                        item.Selected = True
                                    End If
                                Next

                            Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run `ddlmsapplications.SelectedValue = item` you are replacing the current selected value with `item`, so in the end you only have one item selected: the last one in `ms_list`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278117/how-to-get-multiple-selected-items-in-asp-net-listbox-and-show-in-a-textbox) has the solution. You first need to call [`ListBox.ClearSelection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.clearselection?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_ListControl_ClearSelection) to get rid of any current selected items, then loop through the `ListBox.Items` proeprty and set `ListItem.Selected` to `True` for each item you want to select.